# mouse jittering in the middle of screen in XNA

Tags: xna, mouse

When I make the mouse visible, it jitters in the middle of screen. Does anyone know what the problem might be? thanks.

update:

I can't move the mouse.. it just stays at the same point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you setting the mouse position anywhere in your code?

This sounds like the result of an implementation of some "free look" code that sets the mouse position to the centre of the window each frame (so it can read how far it travels and then move it back, to allow for continuous movement without hitting the edge).